# Getting responses from two interdependent JSON generates an error [React Hooks]

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I want to download the data first about the city in which the user is located from **ipstack.com** and then use this information to generate the weather using **openweather.com**. However, the following problem occurs during render:

```
Test.js:20 GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=undefined&lon=undefined&units=metric&appid=(MY API KEY) 400 (Bad Request)
```

The problem is strange because the data I require appears in state eventually:

[image]

My code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Test = () => {
    const [place, setPlace] = useState([]);
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(false)
        fetch(`http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=(MY API KEY)`)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(json => {
                setPlace([json.latitude, json.longitude, json.region_name])
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Error " + err);
            })
    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${place[0]}&lon=${place[1]}&units=metric&appid=(MY API KEY)`)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(json => {
                setWeather(json)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Error " + err);
                setLoading(true);
            })
    }, [place])
    return (
        <>
            {loading && (
                <>
                    <p>{place[0]}</p>
                    <p>{place[1]}</p>
                    <p>{place[2]}</p>
                    <p>{weather.name}</p>
                </>
            )}
        </>
   );
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: weather is array it should be `weather[0].name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the second effect you should fetch data from openweathermap.org only if place array assigned and has correct data. Otherwise on first run you will send invalid data (undefineds instead of positions)

Comment: I did something like that `if(place !==0){fetch()...}`  but now how do i get useEffect to call again when 'place' contains data?

Comment: It will be called automatically since you declare place as dependency of effect. And condition should probably be like this: if (place.length > 0)